# Using $\pi$ to number by X-mas presents

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, pi

**Context:** For this X-max, I will make $50$ presents by myself for my family. I would like to label them so that the labels are totally ordered and all different. However, I think that the traditional $1,2,3,\ldots,50$ is boring.

So, I tried to find a more "funny" way to numerate them and came with an approach based on the representation of $\pi$. After a bit of googling, it turns out that the sequence of labels I'd like to use is the sequence [A064809](https://oeis.org/A064809): "Decimal expansion of $\pi$ written as a sequence of natural numbers avoiding duplicates."

I will denote this sequence by $(x_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$.

The $12$ first terms of this sequence:
$$ \large \pi = \color{red}3.\color{blue}1\color{green}4\color{pink}{1 5}\color{yellow}9\color{grey}2\color{maroon}6\color{teal}5\color{olive}{3 5}\color{purple}8\color{fuchsia}{9 7}\color{aqua}{93}$$
so that $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{12})=(3,1,4,15,9,2,6,5,35,8,97,93)$.

My question is the following:

> Let $S=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ and $x\in S$. Is there an efficient way to find $i$ such that $x_i=x$?

By efficient, I mean that we don't need to compute all the first terms of $(x_k)$ until one detects $x$.

Comment: How do you handle the zeros ? And do you want to get the smallest possible numbers ?

Comment: @Peter I don't see the problem with the zeros... This sequence is well and uniquely defined. The first terms of the sequence are
3, 1, 4, 15, 9, 2, 6, 5, 35, 8, 97, 93, 23, 84, 62, 64, 33, 83, 27, 950, 28, 841, 971, 69, 39, 937, 510, 58, 20, 974, 94, 45, 92, 30
By definition of the sequence, for any $i\neq j$ we have $x_i\neq x_j$. So there shouldn't be an issue about "smallest/biggest" possible numbers.

Comment: We could also choose $3$ , $14$ , $159$ , $2653$ , ... This is what I mean with smallest possible numbers.

Comment: @Peter good point! I did not think at that. However, in this case (which is not the one I'm interested in) the question is obvious isn't it? Just set $i$= number of digits of $x$. The problem with this other sequence is that the $50$-th term is a number with $50$ digits which is not very convenient for the purpose of labeling my presents

Comment: In this case, I do not see a possibility to know which numbers are occupied, if we do not mark or store the chosen numbers.

Comment: @Peter I don't get your problem... Maybe you should have a look at the OEIS page linked in the thread. There is a clear explanation on how to build the sequence.